# PHP & MySql - Compare Date

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

Good Day World,

Need help regarding `mySql & php`. Let say I have a table on my db for `date`. **How do I want to compare the date on the table and the date given by user from a form**?

For example, `date_on_db < date_post`. Then, insert to db. Do I have to use array?

Comment: I'm marking this duplicate because the *answer* is the same, not necessarily the question.

Comment: Thank you @OllieJones. I will look at it.